# SharePoint viewlsts.aspx - Display Description Under Name

Tags: document-library, list-view, css, 2016

is there any way to add the description underneath the Document Library name on viewlists.aspx of a team site? We have just migrated to SP2016 from 10, and all the document library names are project numbers, in 10 we could see the project description in list view. Is there any way that I could change some CSS to display the library description? Please Help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Open list settings > click 'Title, Description and Navigation' under General settings > under Description box, type the text and save. Once you do this, you should see a description for the list in the viewlsts.aspx as well as below the top nav. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately that didn't work. Thank you for the comment.